# SignalR ASP.NET Core 2 context.Token set but not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, jwt

I'm trying to implement jwt token in a signalr logger hub.
But somehow I keep getting an Unauthorized response

JS

```
 let url = '/hub/log?token='+getToken();
 let http = new this.$signalR.HttpConnection(url, options);
 this.connection = new this.$signalR.HubConnection(http);
```

C# ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/hub/"))
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Query["token"];
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };

        options.TokenValidationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidIssuer = settings.JwtValidIssuer,
                ValidAudience = settings.JwtValidAudience,
                IssuerSigningKey = JwtSecurityKey.Create(settings.JwtSecurityKey)
            };
    });
```

The debugger is breaking on 
`context.Token = context.Request.Query["token"];`
and `context.Token` is set

C# Hub

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class LoggerHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IServerManager serverManager;


    public LoggerHub(IServerManager serverManager)
    {
        this.serverManager = serverManager;
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        serverManager.Logger.Log(Shared.Logging.LogLevel.Info, "New websocket connection");
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        serverManager.Logger.Log(Shared.Logging.LogLevel.Info, "a Socket disconnected");
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I check the request type like that before set the token

```
 o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents //For signalR
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest || context.Request.Headers["Accept"] == "text/event-stream")
                        {
                            StringValues accessToken = context.Request.Query["token"];
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
```

Comment: I Already solved it by using
`[Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`